# Why is Eastern Switzerland called Suisse orientale in French?

Tags: toponymes, géographie

I know this is a very niche question, but I live in Eastern Switzerland (German: Ostschweiz) and my colleague needed to translate that into French.

All Google results say it's called “Suisse orientale” in French. This was a bit funny to me, because I started to think of Aladdin and flying carpets. Anyone who has ever been to Eastern Switzerland knows we have as much in common with the orient as a snowy mountain with a sand dune.

I was expecting the translation to be “Suisse Est” or something else with *Est*. Does anybody know why it is “Suisse orientale”?

Comment: Nothing specific to Switzerland: Belgium has 2 provinces called very officially *Flandre occidentale* and *Flandre orientale*.

Comment: The Orient is also called Middle East in english.

Comment: @JeremyGrand At least in [modern usage (past around the middle of the 20th century,)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orient#Current_usage) "the Orient" has normally referred to Eastern and Southeastern Asia, not the Middle East. Granted, prior to the 1800s, [the term did refer to the Middle East](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orient#History_of_the_term).

Comment: @reirab _orient_ and _oriental(e)_ are different words.

Comment: @walen In English, "Oriental" is just the adjective form of "Orient," meaning "of or from the Orient" (i.e. East/Southeast Asia in modern usage.) And, in every language I'm aware of, they have the same common root, from the Latin for 'East'/'Eastern,' as Laurent's answer describes.

Comment: @Greg: Funnily enough, East Flanders (Flandre orientale) is in the western half of Flanders.

Comment: I can not think of any context where "Eastern" in english does not translate to "Oriental(e)". So this is as literal as it gets.

Comment: Just look up the adjectives for cardinal directions, they're directly from latin wind directions: Easterly/Westerly/Northerly/Southerly (wind) is Oriental/Occidental/Septentrional/Meridional [meri-diem: mid-day: (where the sun is in) the middle of the day].

Comment: @Alexis East Germany >>> Allemagne de l'Est not Allemagne orientale.

Comment: @Quora But East Germany is not eastern Germany. _Allemagne de l’Est_ is East Germany; would _Allemagne orientale_ not simply be eastern Germany (i.e., _l’est de l’Allemagne_)?

Comment: @Flater Plenty of those regions are a bit oddly named due to historical reasons. For example, one of the provinces from the Netherlands bordering Belgium is called North Brabant, but it's one of the most southern provinces. The rest of Brabant is in Flanders, but it's *not* called South Brabant.

Comment: @Mast: North Brabant makes sense as it is the northern part of the Brabant region (where in NL Brabant lies is irrelevant). By that same account, "northern Florida" wouldn't be expected to be in the northern half of the US either, just as long as it's the northern region of Florida. However, East Flanders not being in the eastern half of Flanders _doesn't_ follow that same logic.

Comment: @QuoraFeans East = Est, Eastern = Oriental(e)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The adjective "[oriental(e)](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/oriental/56472)" designates something situated to the east, the orient.

The adjective "[occidental(e)](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/occidental/55483)" designates something situated to the west, the occident

Sure you could call it "Suisse de l'est", but using the appropriate adjective is more elegant and in this case is not really ambiguous. For example in French, middle-east is not called "moyen-est", but "moyen-orient".

If one of your friend from another region would describe you as "Mon ami suisse oriental", there indeed could be a certain confusion, but that's another story.

Comment: weird but funny. Merci de m'avoir expliqué

Comment: En France, on connait aussi les départements des Pyrénées, *orientales* pour le 66, à l'est donc, anciennement *Roussillon*. Curieusement (ou pas) celles de l'Ouest (64) sont dites *atlantiques*

Comment: To remember which is which, in french "occire" (from latin "occidere") means "tuer". "L'occident" is where the sun dies, so the west. (That's how I remember it anyway!)

Comment: @Pierre : Absolument. Et symétriquement pour l'*orient* : *oriens* ppres de *orior* : se lever / naître.

Comment: @Pierre > So in order to remember this you need to remember an other (and much less used) word? I actually use "proche-orient" to remember it as I know that it's east of us (or me, at least).

Comment: As I said, that's how I remember. The concept of naming places "orient" and "occident" has always been confusing for me, as it is relative. But the sun moves the same direction for everyone. It comes down to the fact that I know what "occire" means, but I always have to deduct what "occident" means. I made that comment for the trivia and in case it helps someone whose brain would be wired like mine :)

Comment: @Pierre yeah sorry my first sentence is useless. Indeed if you remember it that way, then at least for you it IS a good mnemonic, and why not for others...

Comment: @Pierre. Occidere means "to fall", not "to kill".

Comment: As a side note, we also use Septentrional for "North" and Méridional for "South", even though its less common.

Comment: @fdb The latin verb has [multiple meanings](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/occido) indeed, "to die" and "to kill" are one of them. When used about stars it does mean "to lie down", "to fall" or "to set" though. In french, "occire" only means "to kill".

Comment: Interestingly enough, East Germany was called "Allemagne de l'Est" (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9publique_d%C3%A9mocratique_allemande) and not "Allemagne orientale". Maybe that was influenced by "East Germany" and "Ostdeutschland"? Or maybe "oriental(e)" is slightly archaic (although less so than "septentrional(e)" and "meridional(e)")?

Comment: @rob74 : Peut-être à cause des Ostro-Goths et des Wisi-Goths ;-)

Comment: @Mast Be my guest, use them. They are wrong in contexts like: eastern Switzerland. It would be an outright mistake to use oriental there in English. **What I am saying is simply not controversial**. The answer is confusing unless one really knows English usage. orient and occident in English should not really be there.

Answer (score 8):

As a french native speaker living in Suisse romande, I can confirm that *suisse orientale* is commonly understood and used to speak of the east part of Switzerland (St-Gallen, Graubünden,...).

Though most of time, the whole german part of Switzerland is seen as *suisse allemande* for the people in *suisse romande*. As I lived in Zurich, I noticed that the differenciation between *Ostschweiz*, *Zentralschweiz*, etc. is mostly used by german swiss people themself. Probably because, the accent and dialect changes depending if you comes from Bern, St-Gallen, Zürich, etc.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that *oriental* is the adjective associated to the noun *est*. “Eastern X” and “*X oriental(e)*” are in straightforward correspondance.

In French, you can't just take a noun and use it as an adjective. You often need to add or change a suffix, and sometimes more than that. There is no adjective built directly on *est*¹.

It's very common for “basic” nouns and verbs to have evolved continuously from Latin (*formation populaire*), and for more “fancy” terms to have been introduced during the Middle-Ages in a form that's a lot closer to the Latin (*formation savante*). There's a somewhat similar phenomenon in English with basic words of Germanic origin and fancy words of Romance origin. The cardinal directions in French (*est*, *ouest*, *nord*, *sud*) actually come from English (or more precisely Anglo-Saxon), and can be considered *formations populaires*. They have associated adjectives that come from the names of the cardinal directions in Latin: *[oriental](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/oriental)* (from *[oriens](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oriens#la)*), *[occidental](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/occidental)* (from *[occidens](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/occidens#la)*), *[septentrional](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/septentrional)* (from *[Septentrio](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Septentrio#la)*), *[méridional](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%A9ridional)* (from [meridies](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meridies#la)). The adjectives *oriental* and *occidental* are the “normal” adjectives for east and west. *Méridional* is a little less used, with *sud* being more common as an adjective or apposed noun¹. *Septentrional* is rarely used and there is an adjective *[nordique](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nordique)*, but this adjective is mostly used only with the same meaning as Nordic in English, referring specifically to the [Nordic countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordic_countries).

Other constructions would be possible, for example “Suisse de l'est” (like *[Corse-du-Sud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corse-du-Sud)*, [Corée du Sud](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cor%C3%A9e_du_Sud)) or “Est-Suisse” (like *[Nord-Kivu](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nord-Kivu)*). But “Suisse orientale” follows a common and (to a French speaker) unremarakable pattern, like *[Pyrénées-Orientales](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyr%C3%A9n%C3%A9es-Orientales)*, *[Flandre-Orientale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Province_de_Flandre-Orientale)* and *[Flandre-Occidentale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Province_de_Flandre-Occidentale)*,

¹  <sub>The word *est* is sometimes classified as an adjective in expressions like “*la rive est*” (the east coast/bank) and “*le versant est*” (the east flank [of a mountain]), but I think it would be more accurate to classify it as a noun in apposition, since it is invariable. Adjectives normally agree with the noun in French.</sub>

Comment: There's also *sudiste*, an adjective built directly on *sud*, but it mostly refers to the Confederates during the US Civil War, and sometimes their modern sympathisers. Likewise with nordistes.

Comment: @Eauquidort But does it ever mean “of the south” or “from the south”, as opposed to “partisan of the south”?

Comment: Depends on how strict you want your criterion to be. I mostly commented because it overlaps with Northern and Southern in English (ie the Southern offensive on Northern positions -> L'assaut sudiste sur les positions nordistes)

Answer (score 4):

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/oriental_orientale_orientaux/56472

> Définitions :
>
> Qui est situé à l'est : La côte orientale de la Corse.
>
> Relatif à
> l'Orient : Peuples orientaux.
>
> Qui est propre à l'Orient, à sa culture,
> ses traditions : Musique orientale.
>
> Qui est digne de l'Orient, tel
> qu'il est imaginé dans la culture occidentale : Luxe oriental.

Here is the first definition that is pertinent: Qui est situé à l'est (Who is located in the east).

Read also the article here :

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/oriental

The word oriental has two origines.

> (Adjectif) Du latin orientalis venant de oriens (« orient »).
>
> (Nom)
> (XXe siècle) Car venu en Europe d’Orient.

(...)

> Qui est situé à l’est. Cette ville, située à une altitude de mille
> toises sur le revers oriental des Rocheuses, au bord d’un torrent
> tributaire du Missouri, forme un vaste entrepôt pour les produits
> miniers de la région, et compte de quatorze à quinze mille habitants.
> — (Jules Verne, Le Testament d’un excentrique, 1899, livre 2, chap.
> 12)

The antonyme is *occidental*.